# How to change the google translate widget size which follows the SIMPLE template

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate

I have included google widget with SIMPLE layeout in my web page,It was looking quite small.
Then I tried to increase height and width of widget dropdown box by using css class of goog-te-combo  then there is no changes appearing .How to increase google translate widget with SIMPLE layout.

here is my google translate widget code and css :

```
 <html lang="en-US">
   <style type="text/css"> 
    .goog-te-combo {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL}, 'google_translate_element', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE);
    }
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```